# MySql Error 1064 When assigning schema privileges with MySQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just downloaded and installed the latest MySQL version (5.6) on Windows 8 64bit.
Defaults were used during install and it all ran smoothly.

Using MySQL Workbench I created a schema with one simple table and also created a new user.
On the schema privileges tab I add a new entry for the user, press the Select "All" button to select the privileges and hit Save Changes. As soon as I do this I get he following error:

[image: MySQL Error 1064]

Any ideas why this is happening?
I am very new to DB's so if you have any alternative methods I can try please explain in simple (step by step) terms.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to assign all rights on dev_runeslinger?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Workbench. Do you have a very old version?

Comment: is your database-name and username are same(dev_runeslinger)?

Comment: @BhavikShah Yes to both of your questions. Alvaro has provided the reason for the bug in his answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be bug [#68175](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68175) in MySQL Workbench:

> Database names containing an underscore showing up escaped/ cause SQL Error

It was reported last month and it's still open so you can either downgrade to a version older than 5.2.46 or wait to see whether it's fixed.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro, the rbug report describes exactly my problem. I guess I'll downgrade for now.

Answer (score 5):

When you open an command-line mysql session and choose the database you can give the command

GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,REFERENCES,INDEX,ALTER,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,LOCK TABLES,CREATE VIEW,SHOW VIEW,CREATE ROUTINE,ALTER ROUTINE,EXECUTE,EVENT,TRIGGER ON dev_runeslinger.* TO 'dev_runeslinger'@'localhost';

So it is a case of mis-interpretation/parsing of the _ since it is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it in `phpMyAdmin` by using the following query and also it can be possible from command line as administrator.

`GRANT ALL ON schema_name.* TO 'schemauser_name'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`